# Placing blocks and calculating height of the highest tower

Tags: algorithm

Series of k blocks is given (k1, k2, ..., ki). Each block starts on position ai and ends on position bi and its height is 1. Blocks are placed consecutively. If the block overlaps another one, it is being attached on its top. My task is to calculate the highest tower of blocks.
 I have created an algorithm which time complexity is about O(n^2), but I know there is a faster solution with the usage of skiplist.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Brick
{
    int begin;
    int end;
    int height = 1;
};

bool DoOverlap(Brick a, Brick b)
{
    return (a.end > b.begin && a.begin < b.end)
}

int theHighest(Brick bricks[], int n)
{
    int height = 1;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (bricks[i].height <= bricks[j].height && DoOverlap(bricks[i], bricks[j]))
            {
                bricks[i].height = bricks[j].height + 1;

                if (bricks[i].height > height)
                    height = bricks[i].height;
            }
        } 
    }

    return height;
}
```

[That's an example drawing of created construction.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvvWO.png)

Comment: What's your question? Where is your code?

Comment: can you share the algorithm you created?

Comment: What is the range of ai , bi ?

Comment: I have added a code. Range of ai, bi is unrestriced, for example (5,10), (6,12). I didn't mention that every position is a natural number, sorry for possible misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **2 pointers** after sorting the blocks based on their starting positions, if their starting positions match sort them based on their ending positions. Then simply use the 2 pointers to find the maximum height.

Time complexity : **O(NlogN)**

You can find the demo link [here](https://ideone.com/IUzTyr)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define ii pair<int,int>

bool modified_sort(const pair<int,int> &a,
              const pair<int,int> &b)
{
    if (a.first == b.first) {
        return (a.second <b.second);
    }
    return (a.first <b.first);
}
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector<ii> blocks;
    int n; // no of blocks
    int a,b;
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin>>a>>b;
        blocks.push_back(ii(a,b));
    }
    sort(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), modified_sort);
    int start=0,end=0;
    int max_height=0;
    while(end<n) {
         while(start<end && blocks[start].second <= blocks[end].first) 
         {
            start++;
         }
         max_height = max(max_height,(end-start+1));
         end++;
    }
    cout<<max_height<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward solution (without skip lists):

Create an array `heights`

Iterate through the blocks.

For every block

- Check the existing entries in the heights array for the positions the current block occupies by iterating over them. Determine their maximum.
- Increase the values in the heights array for the current block to the maximum+1 determined in the previous step.
- keep score of the maximum tower you have built during the scan.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have understood me properly. What is the point of creating an array of heights if the height of each block is determined while putting the block on another?

Comment: Not having to go through all other bricks for every brick

Comment: If the possible locations are sparse, use a hash instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is isomorphic to a graph traversal.  Each interval (block) is a node of the graph.  Two blocks are connected by an edge *iff* their intervals overlap (a stacking possibility).  The example you give has graph edges

```
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 5
and node 4 has no edges
```

Your highest stack is isomorphic to the longest cycle-free path in the graph.  This problem has well-known solutions.

BTW, I don't think your n^2 algorithm works for all orderings of blocks.  Try a set of six blocks with one overlap each, such as the intervals [n, n+3] for n in {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}.  Feed all permutations of these blocks to your algorithm, and see whether it comes up with a height of 6 for each.

---

**Complexity**

I think the highest complexity is likely to be sorting the intervals to accelerate marking the edges.  The sort will be **O(n log n)**.  Adding edges is **O(n d)** where **d** is the mean degree of the graph (and n*d is the number of edges).

I don't have the [graph traversal algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) solidly in mind, but I expect that it's **O(d log n)**.

Comment: That's really interesting solution. What is the approximate time complexity of that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can store your already processed blocks in a skip list. The blocks should be ordered by starting position. Then to find overlapping blocks at each step you should search in this skip list which is O(log n) on average. You find first overlapping block then iterate to next and so on until you meet first non-overlapping block.

So on average you can get O(n * (log(n) + m)) where m - is the mean number of overlapping blocks. In the worst case you still get O(n^2).